# Hydrogenation of alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How many structural isomeric alkenes ($\ce{C_6H_{10}}$) can be hydrogenated to give methylcyclopentane? Would there be three? I drew out what I thought was correct but I just want to confirm that there are three.

Answer (score 7):

There are 4 structural isomeric alkenes ($\ce{C_6H_{10}}$) that can be hydrogenated to give methylcyclopentane.

**1-Methycyclopentene**

[image]

**3-Methylcyclopentene**

[image]

**4-Methylcyclopentene**

[image]

**Methylenecyclopentane**

[image]